# cleveref type referencing for writing Constraint(s)

Tags: cleveref, ref

`\cref{eq15,eq16,eq17,eq18}` produces `Eqs. (15) to (18)`.

Some of the equations I want to write as `Constraint`/`constraint`/`Constraints`/`constraints` depending on the position of reference and number of reference(s). Similar to what happens in `\cref`/`\Cref`, it automatically detects number of reference(s) and produce number(s) accordingly. Also, I don't want to change `\cref` for Equations.

Possible? Any help/idea?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
    a+b<2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq4}
    a+b<2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq3}
    a+b<2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
    a+b<2
\end{equation}

\Cref{eq1} should display Equation and \cref{eq1} should display Eq. i.e., normal behaviour of cref. I don't want to change this.

Need some kind of newcommand/macro/package so that I can write constraints (2) to (4). 

%Ex:
%\newref{eq2} = constraint (4)
%\Newref{eq2} = Constraint (4)
%\newref{eq3,eq2,eq4} = constraints (2) to (4)
%\Newref{eq3,eq2,eq4} = Constraints (2) to (4)
%\newref{eq2,eq3} = constraints (3) and (4)
%\Newref{eq2,eq3} = constraints (3) and (4)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try `\crefname{equation}{constraint}{constraints}`?

Comment: Will it not change `equation` too? i.e., after this command, can I use `\cref` to ref Eq.?

Comment: I suggest using `\cref{eq1}` to obtain **Eq. (1)** label by defining (`\crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}`) and `\Cref{eq1}` to obtain **Constraint (1)** label by defining (`\Crefname{equation}{Constraint}{Constraints}`) in the preamble. In that case you only give up the un-capitalization option for **Eq.** and **Constraint** (i.e. inability to obtain eq. and constraint labels in small case letters) but you get all other rules applied (singular/plural/range) for both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may achieve your formatting objective by defining an "alias", called `constraint`, for the `equation` counter. Observe the form of the `\label` instruction for `equation` environments: `\label[constraint]{eq|x|}`, where `x` is in `{2,3,4}`. Using an optional argument tells `cleveref` to use a label name other than the default.

For more information about `cleveref`'s "alias" feature, please see section 6 of the [package's user guide](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf), "Overriding the Cross-Referencing Type".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefalias{constraint}{equation}
\crefname{constraint}{constraint}{constraints}
\Crefname{constraint}{Constraint}{Constraints}
\creflabelformat{constraint}{#2{\upshape(#1)}#3} 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1} a+b=2 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label[constraint]{eq2} a+b<2 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label[constraint]{eq3} a+b>2 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label[constraint]{eq4} a+b\ne2 \end{equation}

\Cref{eq1}; \cref{eq1}.

\Cref{eq2,eq4,eq3}; \cref{eq2,eq4,eq3}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mr.EU - You're most welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This solution depends on defining a new command for using `\cref`/`\Cref` that *temporary* changes their definition when cross-ref an equation. So that at any time the equation can be cross-ref by either their initial label definition or by an additional label (without removing the initial/original one). Both labels can be used for the same equation with any order at any time.

The new command can be for example `\ccref` defined as follows

```
\newcommand*\ccref[1]{\crefname{equation}{constraint}{constraints}\Crefname{equation}{Constraint}{Constraints}\cref{#1}\crefname{equation}{eq.}{eqs.} \Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}}
```

and similarly for defining the upper case `\CCref`

Below are examples of all possible cases while using two labels `eq./eqs./Eq./Eqs.` and `constraint/constraints/Constraint/Constraints`

[image]

The full code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{eq.}{eqs.} % Initial definition of \cref
\Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.} % Initial definition of \Cref
%
\newcommand*\ccref[1]{\crefname{equation}{constraint}{constraints}\Crefname{equation}{Constraint}{Constraints}\cref{#1}\crefname{equation}{eq.}{eqs.} \Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}}
\newcommand*\CCref[1]{\crefname{equation}{constraint}{constraints}\Crefname{equation}{Constraint}{Constraints}\Cref{#1}\crefname{equation}{eq.}{eqs.} \Crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.}}
%
\begin{document}
%
\section{Equations}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq1}
        a+b<2
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq2}
        a+b<2
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq3}
        a+b<2
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq4}
        a+b<2
    \end{equation}

\section{Test single equation}
    \begin{tabular}{l l }
        Command & Output \\
        \hline
    \verb|\cref{eq1}| &  \cref{eq1} \\
    \verb|\Cref{eq1}| &  \Cref{eq1} \\
    \verb|\ccref{eq1}| & \ccref{eq1} \\
    \verb|\CCref{eq1}| &  \CCref{eq1}  \\
    \end{tabular}

\section{Test many equation}

\begin{tabular}{l l }
    Command & Output \\
    \hline
    \verb|\cref{eq1,eq2}| &  \cref{eq1,eq2} \\
    \verb|\Cref{eq1,eq2}| &  \Cref{eq1,eq2} \\
    \verb|\Cref{eq1,eq2,eq4}| &  \Cref{eq1,eq2,eq4} \\
    \verb|\ccref{eq1,eq2}| & \ccref{eq1,eq2} \\
    \verb|\CCref{eq1,eq2}| &  \CCref{eq1,eq2}  \\
    \verb|\CCref{eq1,eq2,eq4}| &  \CCref{eq1,eq2,eq4}  \\
\end{tabular}

\section{Test range of equations}
    \begin{tabular}{l l }
    Command & Output \\
    \hline
    \verb|\cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4}| &  \cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4} \\
    \verb|\Cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4}| &  \Cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4} \\
    \verb|\ccref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4}| & \ccref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4} \\
    \verb|\CCref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4}| &  \CCref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4}  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is cool too.... Thanks.